# OSX paste command not pasting whole line

Tags: bash, macos, paste

I am trying to paste two files together

file ip.txt

```
10.32.216.15
10.23.134.8
10.33.2.37
10.33.84.20
10.33.17.38
```

file obj.txt

```
obj-10.32.216.15
obj-10.23.134.8
obj-10.33.2.37
obj-10.33.84.20
obj-10.33.17.38
```

and I use the command like this:

```
paste ip.txt obj.txt
```

However I get this truncated output:

```
10.32.21obj-10.32.216.15
10.23.13obj-10.23.134.8
10.33.2.obj-10.33.2.37
10.33.84obj-10.33.84.20
10.33.17obj-10.33.17.38
```

The two files are created by grep command in my script earlier. This behavior is also present when I used variables with the command.
Also when I try to specify a delimiter only the second file gets pasted.
Does anyone know what might be the issue? Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Nobody columns from ip.txt on the left and columns from obj.txt on the right, but I have already found the issue - it was line endings

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with line endings, for some reason Windows were set up but Unix were needed.